# How can I adjust the position of the table and the statement from the above picture to the following one?

Tags: math-mode

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\begin{raggedleft}
\begin{tabular}{c| c c c}
      a&b&c&d\\
   \midrule
      a&b&c&d\\
      a&b&c&d\\
      a&b&c&d   
\end{tabular}
\end{raggedleft}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{raggedright}
The table is used..............\\
and then we need to .........\\
Hence................
\end{raggedright}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your example requires `booktabs` but you didn't say...

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htp]%no[h!]
%no\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
%no\begin{raggedleft}
\begin{tabular}{c| c c c}
      a&b&c&d\\
   \midrule
      a&b&c&d\\
      a&b&c&d\\
      a&b&c&d   
\end{tabular}
%no\end{raggedleft}
%no\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
%no\begin{raggedright}
\raggedright
The table is used..............\\
and then we need to .........\\
Hence................
%no\end{raggedright}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```